# WPF Convert hex to UInt

Tags: c#, hex, uint64, uint32

I want to convert Hexadecimal into a UInt. The problem is the following:

when I try this:

```
uint value = Convert.ToUInt32((hex), 16);
```

and the hex is for example 12 bytes size, all works fine, but when I try to convert a hex with 32 bytes size I have this error:

```
value too large or too small for int32
```

Then I try this :

```
ulong = Convert.ToUInt64((hex), 16);
```

and I get this error.

```
value too large or too small for int64
```

Someone Knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Your code samples do not compile. Do you want to **parse** a string containging some number in hex format? show as an example...

Comment: can you please give us an example of string you're using?

Comment: You are right sorry, the string is a hexadecimal number. For example : I have the hexadecimal number D34128 and I want 13844776 decimal number, but when I have a hexadecimal 32 bytes size, I get the error.

Comment: I tried: Convert.ToUInt32("D34128", 16); works. Could you give us concrete example when you get this error?

Comment: Try this hexadecimal : 234567891123456789223456789. If I try this:  Convert.ToUInt64("1234567891123456789223456789", 16); and this Convert.ToUInt32("1234567891123456789223456789", 16) I get a error.

Comment: Value you try to convert is to big see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Sowi error is correct:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.uint64.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx
0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF is max Uint64 value. 
You tried to input:
0x1234567891123456789223456789 what is much bigger value.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I cut the hexadecimal number like this:

Hex = 1234567891123456789223456789

```
ulong result= Convert.ToUInt64(12345678911234, 16);
result += Convert.ToUInt64(56789223456789, 16);
```

That resolve my problem. Thanks for the replies, made me think!!!

Comment: You are sure that it's good?
e g 0x11 = 17 in your approach it will be 2

Comment: But what you need for? What is the case? Why you have to use so big numbers?